# How to audit hibernate entity access

Tags: spring, hibernate, auditing

I need to log not only modifications, but every access to Entity.
I've looked into EntityListeners and Envers but couldn't find anything usefull.

Comment: You need to implement it yourself.

Comment: You can use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to do this. Basically: an annotation which will add your logging code everywhere in the entities. This is quite quite simple to do with Spring.